# Sending data in application/x-www-form-urlencoded format from postman to Web API Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I am sending some data from postman to web api controller but its not hitting am I missing something?

here is my code given below.

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("[controller]")]
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public ActionResult<Root> PostData([FromBody] Root inputData)
{
    //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //sb.Append("q:" + inputData.q + " siteKey:" + inputData.siteKEY + " siteCredentials:" + inputData.siteCredential + " user:" + inputData.userID + " patient:" + inputData.patientID + " uuid:" + inputData.UUID);
    return Ok(inputData); //(sb.ToString());
}
```

[image]

Comment: What error(s) are you seeing?  404?

Comment: 405 method not allowed

Comment: could you show Root class pls?

Comment: I might just be spit balling here, but if you are using the Weatherforecast controller which is generated automatically when starting the program, your api controller itself will have the `Route("[Controller]")` tag. So if you put another tag above your endpoint as well, then your URL you are trying to find should be: `host:port/WeatherForecast/WeatherForecast`. If that is not the issue, trying changing `[FromBody]` to `[FromForm]`

Comment: public class Root
    {
        public Args args { get; set; }
        public string data { get; set; }
        public Files files { get; set; }
        public Form form { get; set; }
        public Headers headers { get; set; }
        public Json json { get; set; }
        public string url { get; set; }
    }

Comment: Hi @RussianFederation, what's the status code do you get if you change `FromForm` to `FromBody`? 405 method not allowed is because this request url does not match any post action but  matches get/put/delete action.

Answer (score 1):

The `[FromForm]` attribute is for incoming data from a submitted form sent by the content type `application/x-www-url-formencoded` while the `[FromBody]` will parse the model the default way, which in most cases are sent by the content type `application/json` , from the request body.

Answer (score 0):

application/x-www-form-urlencoded is more or less the same as a query string on the end of the URL. So remove

```
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
```

and when using Postman you better use raw and json to create input parameters

Answer (score 0):

Try to turn off “ssl cerificate verification” on Postman setting
just go to Setting -> general -> turn off ssl cerificate verification

Answer (score 0):

```
[HttpPost]
[Route("[api/Home/PostData]")]                   //check here please specify controllername and index name
[Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")]
public ActionResult<Root> PostData([FromBody] Root inputData)
{
    //StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    //sb.Append("q:" + inputData.q + " siteKey:" + inputData.siteKEY + " siteCredentials:" + inputData.siteCredential + " user:" + inputData.userID + " patient:" + inputData.patientID + " uuid:" + inputData.UUID);
    return Ok(inputData); //(sb.ToString());
}
```

add controller name and index name

```
[Route("[api/Home/PostData]")]                   //check here please specify controllername and index name
```